# smoothing linear graph but keep the spikes

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, linear-programming

how can I smooth a linear graph, but keep the spikes ?

the graph are speed points per second, so it goes up and down frequently (like sinus curve), but sometimes there are spikes, like the speed reaches a maximum for just one second and in the next two seconds it went down to zero. 
when I try to smooth the graph with moving averages, I destroy this short spikes, and the graph really looks like a sinus curve.

What i need is this smooth curve, but when there is a max speed, the curve should show it, and also if there is a short acceleration or stop, I would still like to see this.

an idea I had, is to first identify the spikes. 
then identify big differences within a short time mac 5s.
now I do moving average, when i came close to either a spike or big difference, I use this point instead of moving average.

but this fells not right, and also complicated. 
probably there is a much better solution for it ?

and I guess this one is not working for my second graph, which is like a heartbeat graph. here I just want to display the heartbeat as a sinus like curve (data should be like that) but also keep the very short spikes.

(I'm not a mathematician, please try to explain possible answer that I can also understand them)

**Update**

here is an example. the blue one is of my first type and the green one is the second type.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ4V4.jpg

Comment: Google "Moving average"

Comment: i did already, thats why i figured out that it will not work, as seen in this screen: [](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Moving_average#/media/File:Moving_Average_Types_comparison_-_Simple_and_Exponential.png) its kills the spikes. which i need to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first think you need to decide on is what is a spike and what is not. 
Consider the following graphs, surely there are spikes on left-most one, but what about the right one? If these are spikes, then how would you smooth that graph without increasing the sampling frequency? If these are not spikes, then what about the graphs in the middle, where do you put the threshold?

[image: spikes graph]

If your data is not too big, then as a first approach I would recommend using Fourier transform - for example by cutting the high frequencies you make your graph less jagged and you should be able to keep the significant spikes. Of course, some  especially thin spikes might get removed, but this is, among others, what "less jagged" means.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I will try this Fourier transform, (need to find a simple explained one)  i added a Link to an example graph, for me it look like your first 3 examples, but the spikes are shorter.or as in my first graph(blue one) its just highest value of the graph but compered to points before not a spike

Comment: what if I use a moving average but only for parts of the graph, so I check, if the values in range are inside an average, if come to a spike, its far out, so I stop here. use the moving average data, add the spike and start a new moving average calculation after the spike, so splitting the graph into separate  graphs and connect them later again ? could this also work and how is this compared to a Fourier transform ?

Comment: @Gabriel You can do some FFT processing with Matlab/Octave or even with some audio software (e.g. [audacity](http://audacityteam.org/)). As for the moving average for parts of the graph, how would you deal with a case such as the right diagram?

Comment: FFT is a short for Fourier Transform ? I don't have Matlab or similar, just need to program this graph for my self, maybe there is a trail version with which I can try different algorithms before implementing it in code ? . The last graph will not happen, all graphs I need to display will look like the one I posted (as link), so either like blue: rectangles, or like green: heartbeat, if there is a small gap inside a rectangle, it can be smooth, that would be ok.

Comment: ah ok FFT ist Fast Fourier Transform

Comment: @Gabriel Octave is free (but there are bunch of other libraries that would do the same, for example in Python).